# How to update a specific row by QThread or emit signal to a specific column of a row

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to update a **row** by using **QThread**, or **emit the signal to a specific column of that row**

```
    firstName   lastName      Age      Status
   +----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
   |  xxxxx   |  xxxxxxx  | xxxxxxx |   OK         |
   |  xxxxx   |  xxxxxxx  | xxxxxxx |   Uploading  |
   +----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to update the column status: If the data is uploaded successfully then it will be `OK`, else `Uploading`

**The code that emit the data:**

```
self.signal.emit(firstName, lastName, Age, status)
```

So, **for every new data that I have upload, I will insert a new row to show the data:**

```
    def Show(self, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4):

        #count row
        row = self.infos.rowCount()
        
        #insert a new row
        self.infos.insertRow(row)
        self.infos.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(txt1))
        self.infos.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(txt2))
        self.infos.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(txt3))
        self.infos.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(txt4))
```

But the problem that comes to me is that whenever the **status** is **updated**, it will **automatically append one more row showing the same first 3 columns and the status is changed**. W**hat I needed is that the row will update itself, not inserting any other rows**.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming that the thread keeps track of the order of new elements, just emit the signal with the index, and use the index as row: if the row exists, then update the relative column, otherwise create a new one like you are already doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a for loop to iterate the rows in your table, and compare contents of each of the cells to the text received from the signal.  Once it finds a match it can then update the the status cell only and break the loop at that point.

```
    def Show(self, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4):

        #count row
        row = self.infos.rowCount()
        
        for i in range(row):
            cell1 = self.infos.item(i, 0)
            cell2 = self.infos.item(i, 1)
            cell3 = self.infos.item(i, 2)
            if cell1.text() == txt1 and cell2.text() == txt2 and cell3.text() == txt3:
                self.infos.item(i, 3).setText(txt4)
                break
```

This wouldn't work if you had rows with identical information though.